# Сортировка прописных и строчных букв

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Всем привет!
Как сделать так, чтобы вместо массива:

```
["Connecticut", "Land", "Massachusetts", "Old", "Thirteen", "Vermont", "and", "land", "land", "of", "of", "the"],
```

выводился массив:

```
[ "and", "land", "land", "of", "of", "the", "Connecticut", "Land", "Massachusetts", "Old", "Thirteen", "Vermont"]
```

Возможно с помощью метода `.map` или `.filter` пробегаться по готовому элементу и если 1-ая буква прописная, то закидывать в локальную переменную типо `lowCase`, тоже самое для `Upcase`. А потом сконкатить.

```
const sort = (sentence) =>{
  const arr =  sentence.replace(/[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]/g, " ").split(' ').filter(i => i!=="").sort() 
  return arr.sort()

}

sort("Land of the Old Thirteen! Massachusetts land! land of Vermont and Connecticut!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции для сортировки можно проверять: Если первая буква большая, сделать её маленькой, если маленькая - сделать большой, и сравнивать как обычно:

```js
console.log( sort("Land of the Old Thirteen! Massachusetts land! land of Vermont and Connecticut!") );

function sort(sentence) {
  return sentence.match(/[a-zа-яё]+/gi).sort(_sorter);

  /***/
  function _sorter(a, b) {
    a = _toggleCase(a);
    b = _toggleCase(b);

    return (a < b) ? -1 : 1;
  }

  function _toggleCase(str) {
    let upper = (str[0].toUpperCase() === str[0]);
    return str[ upper ? "toLowerCase" : "toUpperCase" ]();
  }
};
```

P.s. флажок `i` в регулярном выражении - "insensitive", возьмет и большие, и маленькие буквы. А `.match()` и так возвращает массив совпадений, без необходимости каких-то других операций.